# How to use case statement to declare a local variable for a subsequent subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to declare a local variable depending on the case and then fire a common subquery?

Pseudo code:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
      WHEN TABLE.TYPE = 'STUDENT'  variable  = "UNIVERSITY"
      WHEN TABLE.TYPE = 'EMPLOYEE' variable = "EMPLOYER"
     (Some big query here it has a common joins / groupings but the variable changes)
   END AS NAME
FROM TABLE
```

Looking for a SQL Server solution.

Scenario is like this - I have a query that lists some member information . Now I need to get some addendum data to an existing query - I mean result set won't change . I can actually join but then I have to filter out many things - Does that make sense ? Imagine I was display all the members in the table and someone asks me to show the univeristy name or the employer name . And the biggest problem is a member can have more than one university he attended - same for employer . Isn't joins really bad on performance in this case ? Since there are many one to many stuff . Also please note I finally display only 10 records as part of pagination so I thought I should do a case statement .

Comment: "big query" means multiple records, but you want to assign it to a single variable?

Comment: "big query" that returns a single name unfortunately :)

Comment: Dynamic SQL or CTE (WITH clause) might be options.

Comment: Your pseudo code is unclear. Why the *big query* is in the case when statement ?

Comment: I tried to explain it . Do you think it makes sense ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @variable  varchar(10)

SELECT  @variable = 
CASE
  WHEN t.TYPE = 'STUDENT'  THEN 'UNIVERSITY'
  WHEN t.TYPE = 'EMPLOYEE' THEN 'EMPLOYER'
  ELSE 'Undefined'
END
FROM TableName t
```

[MSDN - SELECT @local_variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259186%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> If the SELECT statement returns more than one value, the variable is
>   assigned the last value returned.

Comment: Where do I put the subquery now ? In the case statement or outside of it ? The "big query" is the key to deriving the value :)

Comment: @Nishant:  it belongs to the main query (behind `FROM ...`)not into the case statetement.